# C#: Calling method in another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Following scenario:
I have a class with some GUI elements (winforms). This class has a update method which changes things on the controls.
I also have a FileSystemWatcher. This object gives me a callback whenever a file changes. In that case I call the update method.

As you might guess this makes the application crash. The reason: the callback from the FileSystemWatcher is in another thread that the one that created the controls. If I then call the update method it can't access the controls.

What is the way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It is trivial for FSW, assign the SynchronizingObject property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `Control.Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`, see in-depth reference [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The top voted answer this this Question looks like it might do the trick:

[C# Windows Forms Application - Updating GUI from another thread AND class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928195/c-windows-forms-application-updating-gui-from-another-thread-and-class)