# How to convert 'Run on UI' Aspect from WPF to Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dispatcher, postsharp

I was trying to implement an aspect following a WPF example, but I can't figure out how to make it work for WinForms.

```
class RunOnUIThreadAttribute : IMethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        DispatcherObject dispatchedObj = (DispatcherObject)args.Instance;
        if (dispatchedObj.CheckAccess())
        {
            args.Proceed();
        }
        else
        {
            dispatchedObj.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => args.Proceed()));
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get the equivalent of `Dispatcher` working on Windows Forms?

Comment: Do you know how to switch to the UI thread in Windows Forms outside of an aspect?

Comment: Helpful SO links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928195/c-sharp-windows-forms-application-updating-gui-from-another-thread-and-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Answer (score 2):

If `args.Instance` is a `Control`, you could use `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke`, instead of their WPF counterparts:

```
class RunOnUIThreadAttribute : IMethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        Control c = (Control)args.Instance;
        if (!c.InvokeRequired)
        {
            args.Proceed();
        }
        else
        {
            c.Invoke((Action)(() => args.Proceed()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1012732: Need more help?